# TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'REDUCE_PROD' version '1'

Tags: arduino, tensorflow-lite, tflite, tinyml

I am using a Seeed Studio XIAO to play some machine learning.
I follow the tutorial[here](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/XIAO-BLE-Sense-TFLite-Getting-Started/)

The model in this example seems to have an input size of `[None, time_steps * num_features]`. In its case, the input instance to the model is `[1, 119 samples * 6 IMU features]`.

I could also run the .ino file on my Seeed Studio board without any errors.

However, I built and trained a model with an input size of `[None, 30(time_steps), 6(num_features)]`.
Basically, my model just had `Input layer (None, 30, 6), 2 dense layers, a flatten layer, and a final dense layer (None, 4).`
I was able to convert the model to `.tflite` and `.h`. But when I loaded it to Arduino, the Serial Port showed error:

20:26:45.976 -> Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'REDUCE_PROD' version '1'. An older version of this builtin might be supported. Are you using an old TFLite binary with a newer model?
20:26:45.976 ->
20:26:45.976 -> Failed to get registration from op code REDUCE_PROD

Anyone has an idea?

I also noticed that `Flatten()` is not supported by tflite micro, then I used `Reshape()` in my model. However, same error was shown in the Serial Port.

In TensorFlow Lite for Microcontroller applications, what should I do to run a model with an input size `[None, time_steps, num_features]`?